# rich:datatable -- zebra striping with rowClasses attribute does not work!

Tags: css, richfaces, zebra-striping

I am trying to style a table with "zebra" coloured rows, however, for some reason, the rowClasses attribute does not seem to work (edit: I see no colours at all applied to the table).

I defined the style as follows:

```
<style>
.even-row {
   background-colour: #fcefa1;
}
.odd-row {
   background-colour: #f7f7f7;
}
</style>
```

And the dataTable itself looks like this:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.labels}" var="label" rowClasses="even-row, odd-row">  
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{label}"/> 
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Any idea as to why this might not be working? (Perhaps I misunderstand what the rowClasses attribute's role is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The British Spelling of Doom ate a day of my life!

Should be `background-color` instead of `background-coloUr`.